# Metabase caching works for normal question but not for pivot question

Tags: caching, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, metabase

My Metabase is connected to Snowflake. I have caching enabled at Metabase but it is not working for pivot queries. And after some debugging of the network response, I found that **ignore-cached-results?** parameter is set to True only for the pivot query. Is there a way to set this to **False**?

Notice the **ignore-cached-results** parameter in the two responses below.

Response for normal query:

```
"cached":true,"database_id":3,"started_at":"2022-02-03T17:13:49.098629Z","json_query":{"constraints":{"max-results":10000,"max-results-bare-rows":2000},"type":"query","middleware":{"js-int-to-string?":true,"ignore-cached-results?":false,"process-viz-settings?":false},"database":3,"query":{"source-table":142},"async?":true,"cache-ttl":29430000},"average_execution_time":5677,"updated_at":"2022-01-31T14:28:02.451881Z","status":"completed","context":"question","row_count":2000,"running_time":546}
```

response for pivot query:

```
"json_query":{"type":"query","query":{"source-table":226,"breakout":[["field",4141,null],["field",4146,null],["expression","pivot-grouping"]],"aggregation":[["sum",["field",4034,null]]],"expressions":{"pivot-grouping":["abs",0]}},"database":3,"constraints":{"max-results":10000,"max-results-bare-rows":2000},"middleware":{"js-int-to-string?":true,"ignore-cached-results?":true,"add-default-userland-constraints?":true},"cache-ttl":374400,"async?":true},"average_execution_time":null,"status":"completed","context":"question","row_count":15,"running_time":53}
```

**Query payload for normal question:**

[image]

**Query payload for pivot question:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE;